# Am I going mad? c# / static modifier

Tags: c#, static-variables

I have the below code, oddly enough it keeps on returning the same value (even though `filename`) is different, if i call it more than once in the same request.

Ive just stepped through the code and even `stringbytes` is exactly the same (i.e. GetBytes(string)) is returning the same value.

```
    public static string Base64EncodeString(string filename)
    {
        var stringbytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(filename);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stringbytes);
    }
```

Comment: if `stringbytes` is the same, then `filename` is the same. Put some code in that prints the values to the console.

Comment: This should work. Are you looking at it in the debugger? Maybe log the values of filename and the base-64 string on each call.

Comment: @Daniel: That's not *quite* true. Several different values of `filename` could all have characters which can't be encoded by `Encoding.Default`, they could all be replaced by the encoded form of '?' :)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but are you sure you want the system dependent default encoding instead of a fixed encoding like UTF8? The default encoding can't even represent all unicode strings.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me.

Comment: And another way my statement is a simplification: what if the default encoding is changed between calls to the OP's method? Not only could two different strings map to the same bytes, but the same string could easily map to two different sets of bytes. But... it's more likely that the OP is just getting confused.

Comment: can you post some input/output you are getting/using

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're not seeing what you think you're seeing. That method *won't* return the same value if you call it with different values of filename... unless you're using characters which aren't supported by `Encoding.Default`. (I wouldn't suggest using `Encoding.Default` unless you *really* want a platform-specific encoding.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. If it's not an Encoding issue as suggested by Jon Skeet i would guess that you have a static fileName and/or stringbytes variable somewhere and that the posted code is not 100% the same as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the files that you are loading. It is possible that you just copied the file that you are opening, gave it a different name and did not modify the content.